# Saving image patches into several folders based on associated values

Tags: image, saving-data

I am trying to save a lot of images into 5 different folders. The sorting mechanism is based on an associated value with the image. So far I've sorted it into two folders with the following code

```
if measurements.ni[idx] < 25:
                    pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/1/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')   
else: 
                pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/2/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')
```

The code throws all images with a value below 25, into 1 folder and the rest into another folder.

Now I want to do that with 5 folders with varying ranges such as this primitive embarassing example that doesnt work. But I think it illustrates the point.

```
       if measurements.ni[idx] < 25:
                pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/1/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')   
            else if measurements.ni[idx] = (25, 100):
                pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/2/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')
            else if measurements.ni[idx] = (100, 250):
                pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/3/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')
            else if measurements.ni[idx] = (250, 800):
                pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/4/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')
            else if measurements.ni[idx] > 800:
                pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/5/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')
```

How would I go about doing this? The value range would be <25, 25-100, 100-250, 250-800, >800.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
 if measurements.ni[idx] < 25:
                    pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/1/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')   
    if measurements.ni[idx] > 25 < 100:
                    pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/2/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')
    if measurements.ni[idx] > 100 < 250:
                    pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/3/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')
    if measurements.ni[idx] > 250 < 800:
                    pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/4/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')
    if measurements.ni[idx] > 800:
                    pyplot.imsave(project_dir + '/classes/5/' + str(measurements.id_dedup[idx]) + '.png' ,img_patch, format='png')
```